# Best spline method for closed curves

Tags: curves, spline

What is the best spline method I can use to obtain a closed curve for the following data?

Note that I will need to obtain the derivative as in every point there will be a vector that is perpendicular to the contour curve (the shape does not have to be a "circle like" as the example, but can be any closed shape).

[image]

Comment: You points are noisy and it is unclear if you want an interpolating or approximating curve.

Comment: looks that OP wants an interpolating (value+deriv.) curve: is it so ?

Comment: @GCab, yes. and the shape does not have to be "circle like", it can be any shape.

Comment: Do you **have** derivative (or tangent, or normal) information, at the outset, of do you want to be able to calculate this information from the curve after you've constructed it.

Comment: @bubba, I would like to calculate the curvature as well.

Comment: OK. Fine. No problem. But what's the answer to my question? It makes a big difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can construct a closed b-spline curve, as described [here](https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve-closed.html).

I don't know if this is the "best" method -- only you can decide what you mean by "best".

If you know the curve normal at each point, then the problem is simpler, but I can't tell whether this is the case, based on the wording of your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is meant to be complementary to *bubba*'s answer and to the reference cited therein, which well explain the general approach in Cartesian coordinates.

To my experience and intuition, when we are dealing with *closed* curves, considering to work in polar coordinates might be of advantage.

that would mean to:
 - move the reference system at the centroid of the cloud;
 - convert the points and the normal vectors into polar c.;
 - perform the spline method in $r,\theta$.

The advantage  of working in polar c. is clear when you note that $r=const.$ is a circle, and the added terms will account for the deviation from that.

Also, since $r(\theta)$ is intrinsically periodic,  it might be interesting to interpolate through [Trigonometric Polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_polynomial).

From the mathematical point of view, the choice of the reference system is quite arbitrary, and mainly dictated by computational advantage.

If instead the curve originates from a physical model, the choice will be oriented by physical considerations. For instance the physical motivation of the *Spline* method (as the word reminds) is to approximate the curve through a ductile wire, so in the $x,y$ plane. While, if it is the orbit of a particle in a central field ...

Comment: **to the anonymous downvoter** if not too much bothering, I would like to know the reason of your criticism: learning from mistakes is great . thanks

Comment: I did not downvote, but while your suggestion will apply well to a circular contour, it will not apply to a generalized closed contour of any shape. I hoped that in this post people will list methods and algorithms and raise their advantages and disadvantages according to their experience.

Comment: @jarhead: understood, and I tried to better explain my view.

Answer (score 0):

For an interpolating closed curve you can use a parametric spline with periodic boundary condition:

1. Create a time-coordinate, e.g. proportional to the distance of two adjacent grid points: $t_{i+1}=t_i+\sqrt{(x_{i+1}-x_i)^2+(y_{i+1}-y_i)^2})$
2. Create two splines for each $x$ and $y$ coordinate as a function of time. Set boundary conditions to be periodic, i.e. $f'(t_1)=f'(t_n)$.

In R you can do something like

```
# generate some input data
n=10
phi=sort(runif(n,0,2*pi))
r=rnorm(n,10,0.5)
X=r*cos(phi)
Y=r*sin(phi)
plot(X,Y)
# add first point to the end to create a closed loop
X=append(X,X[1])
Y=append(Y,Y[1])

# create time vector (traverse at constant speed)
T=vector(length=length(T))
T[1]=0
for(i in 2:length(Y)) T[i]=T[i-1]+norm(c(X[i]-X[i-1], Y[i]-Y[i-1]), type="2")

# setup periodic splines for both x and y coordinate
sx=splinefun(T,X,method="periodic")
sy=splinefun(T,Y,method="periodic")

# plot splines
Tplot=seq(T[1],tail(T,n=1),by=0.02)
Xplot=sx(Tplot)
Yplot=sy(Tplot)
lines(Xplot,Yplot)
```

The spline also contains information regarding derivatives: $\text{derivative} = (sx'(t), sy'(t))$.

```
# plot some derivatives and normals
Tplot=seq(T[1],tail(T,n=1),by=2.0)
for(t in Tplot)
{
    x = sx(t)
    y = sy(t)
    arrows(x,y,x+sx(t,deriv=1),y+sy(t,deriv=1),length=0.05) # derivative
    arrows(x,y,x+sy(t,deriv=1),y-sx(t,deriv=1),length=0.05) # normal
}
```

This gives

[closed spline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHQ9k.png)
[closed spline with derivative and normal arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRfPM.png)